# Using MultiBinding when DataGridColum header was customized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding, gridviewcolumn

I'm custmozing the DataGridColumns of a ListView.

I have many situations :

1- somtimes, the column header is just one word 'Id', in this case I use this code :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"
                Header="Id" />
```

2- sometimes, the column header is composed of many word, in this case i display them in multilines, using a TextBlock with TextWrapping :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="85"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManyWordsColumnHeader}" >
    <GridViewColumnHeader>
        <TextBlock Text="Many words column header"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
</GridViewColumn>
```

3- sometimes, the content of the lines is Multibinded (many properties in the same time), like this :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Fist name & last name">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:PersonClass">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

What should I do if I have a column header name composed of many word and the content of line should be multibinded to many properties ?

In others words : I want to combine the second and the third case together !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really played with `GridView`, but this approach seems logical for me to try (just in case you haven't). Simply combine XAML from point 3 with point 2  :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="85" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:PersonClass">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <GridViewColumnHeader>
        <TextBlock Text="Many words column header"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
</GridViewColumn>
```

There you have a column with "*column header name composed of many word and the content of line multibinded to many properties*".

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Change the Content of your header to be a ListView, with the
   ItemSource set to the list of caption rows.
2. Add a `MultiValueConverter` that takes all of the values from all of the
   binding and returns a string delimited by Environment.NewLine.